# Getting 401 Unauthorized error on google API

Tags: google-drive-api

I am learning how to use Google Drive API to upload a file and I am getting this error:

```
"Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:\n{\n \"error\": \"unauthorized_client\",\n \"error_description\": \"Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this me (truncated...)\n"
```

I think this stem from a wrong configuration of my service account. When I created my service account, I didn't use Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation and just used the generated json key.

Attached here is a screenshot of my IAM & ADMIN [image]

I also enabled API for google drive, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a client id for the service account and with that id you have to enable the SCOPE in security - advanced configuration

Comment: kindly include the link to the advanced configuration page

Answer (score 0):

this is my error case:

```
 Status: Status{code=UNAUTHENTICATED, description=Failed computing credential metadata, cause=java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'int com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException.getAttemptCount()'
```

because it  ads.properties exists empty string, example:

```
api.googleads.clientSecret="GOCSPX--xxxxxxxxxxxxx  "
```

please google office solution

https://groups.google.com/g/AdWords-API/c/mjeB_pYz3hI